# django nginx configuration issue

Tags: django, nginx

I am encountering an issue with my nginx django setting.
Well, when I load the project using their development server everything is ok.

When I load it from nginx, it looks it's not really loading good project.

I made a test, I edited the settings.py file leaving a syntax error and well it didn't load on the internal server of django, but, it loaded with nginx. So I guess nginx isn't linked to the right config but I can't get why as I only created one project.

Config file is the following (nginx):

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name sub.example.com;
access_log  /var/www/sub.example.com/log/access.log;
error_log /var/www/sub.example.com/log/error.log;

## Default location
location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
}

 location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
                  alias /var/www/sub.example.com/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
                  expires 30d;
              }

              location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
                  alias /var/www/sub.example.com/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
                  expires 30d;
              }

}
```

Comment: How are you starting FastCGI?

Comment: Yep I did start fastcgi using the manage.py

Comment: How exactly? And please check if you have restarted it after your code changed.